# Android Device's Home and Menu Buttons

Tags: android, permissions, device

I want nothing to do,When I click the home button and menu button. I wrote a code. I have got all android devices.Code is running Samsung devices, but code isn't running other adroid devices.Please help.

```
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 0xffffff);
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override these two method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

   return true;
 }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

When u call these two method, it'll override the default function of these keys...

Comment: No. If I click the home or menu button, buttons shouldn't work.

Comment: This is running Samsung Device but code isn't running other android devices.

Comment: yes I tried. I want to : My code is running Samsung Device but code isn't running other android devices.